# Can we calculate the difference between two hash checksums?

Tags: javascript, hash, md5, checksum, sha256

More exactly, let's say we have two images and we do the MD5 or SHA-256 of each.
Is there an algorithm to calculate the percentage difference/similarity between the two checksums? To say image_1 is 26% similar to image_2 ?

I don't necessarily want MD5 or SHA, any other fast mechanism will do.

*LE : ANY fast mechanism for determining percentage of difference/similarity between two large data strings will do (I think Damerau-Levenshtein would prove slow)

Comment: You can compute the difference between the hashes, but it won't tell you anything about the difference between the original images.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't need to know exact differences, only how different. So you state that distance between two hash strings won't be identical in percentage to distance between the source images.

Comment: Good checksums are explicitly designed to prevent this kind of comparison.

Comment: There won't be any relationship at all - on average changing a single input bit will change 50% of the bits in the output hash.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you calculate the difference between two hashes?**

Sure.

**Can you use that difference to infer anything about the original files?**

No, that's the entire point of a [cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function); even a minor change should generate a significantly different hash. Otherwise they would lose their usefulness in security related aspects.